# Swagger UI not sending array correctly

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to send multiple values (an array) (refer to on line 93 in spec ->... name: recipients[] ...)

The problem I am facing is the Swagger-ui call the endpoints as below:

**Actual**

```
recipients[]=value1%2Cvalue2
```

**Expected**

```
recipients[]=value1&recipients[]=value2
```

The %2C means , (comma).

Below are the required details
swagger-ui version 2.1.1
Below is the link for content of the swagger spec file reproducing the issue:
http://pastebin.com/V3ZuCjVz

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the way to specify this is to add `collectionFormat: multi`

```
- name: recipients[]
  in: formData
  description: Email addresses for recipients (multiple values allowed).
  required: true
  type: array
  collectionFormat: multi
  items:
      type: string
```

Possible values from http://swagger.io/specification/ are:

- csv - comma separated values foo,bar.
- ssv - space separated values foo bar.
- tsv - tab separated values foo\tbar.
- pipes - pipe separated values foo|bar.
- multi - corresponds to multiple parameter instances instead of
  multiple values for a single instance foo=bar&foo=baz. This is valid
  only for parameters in "query" or "formData".

Comment: I tried this, but still not working :(. here is the swagger spec after the changes: http://pastebin.com/t47xjFQw   (refer to recipients)

Comment: I have reported this issue with swagger-ui (also swagger-js) project. The team is responsive and they are working on it. These are the urls:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2067       
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/749